# Why can't i write to a file in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

When I run,

```
Text = "Hello"
newFileName = (input("What would you like to name this file? "))
newFile = open(newFileName, 'w')
newFile.write(Text)
print("Saved as ", newFileName, "!")
```

It makes the file. However the file is empty. Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Comment: it's not empty for me, can you write what exactly did you type in input? also prefer with open(newFileName, 'w') as f:  since it handles closing the file and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close the file object `newFile`, otherwise the buffer that you are really writing to when you call `newFile.write()` might not get flushed to the actual file on disk. That is, add this line at the end:

```
newFile.close()
```

Python has a nice construct for dealing with this "setting up and tearing down" logic, known as [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), used by the `with` statement. Using this, you can change your code to

```
Text = "Hello"
newFileName = input("What would you like to name this file? ")
with open(newFileName, 'w') as newFile:
    newFile.write(Text)
print("Saved as ", newFileName, "!")
```

When the `with` block is done, the file is automatically closed, even if some error happens in the middle.